# WP_Customize_Color_Control omitting # symbol

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-customizer

I am developing a theme and am struggling with `WP_Customize_Color_Control`.

Sometimes it includes the # symbol before the color's hex and sometimes it doesn't. I have triple checked my code and cannot see why `header_textcolor` is the only color to omit it's # symbol before the hex value in the resulting stylesheet (which prevents it being used).

Excerpt from functions.php:

```
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_backgroundcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Background Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_backgroundcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_brandtextcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Brand Text Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_brandtextcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_brandhovertextcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Brand Hover Text Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_brandhovertextcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_textcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Text Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_textcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_hovertextcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Hover Text Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_hovertextcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_activetextcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Header Active Text Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'header_activetextcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'backgroundcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Background Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'backgroundcolor',
) ) );
$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'footer_backgroundcolor', array(
  'label'      => __( 'Footer Background Color' ),
  'section'    => 'colors',
  'settings'   => 'footer_backgroundcolor',
) ) );
```

Excerpt from dynamic CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'backgroundcolor', '#dddddd' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_backgroundcolor', '#f8f8f8' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_brandtextcolor', '#777777' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_brandhovertextcolor', '#5e5e5e' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_activetextcolor', '#555555' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', '#777777' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_hovertextcolor', '#333333' ); ?>;
}
```

As two ## symbols or no # symbols prevents the value being set my current workaround is:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: <?= get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', '#777777' ); ?>;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #<?= get_theme_mod( 'header_textcolor', '#777777' ); ?>;
}
```

however there has to be something wrong here. The other color settings work fine.

**EDIT:**

Changing "header_textcolor" to any other name ("foobar" and "navbar_textcolor" in my testing) also resolved this issue.

Am thinking that "header_textcolor" is a reserved value or I've corrupted my Wordpress installation somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently not able to write it all down for you but you can always **use a sanitizer** (Wordpress has one build in) to add an # if its not present. 
Also as far as i know u always need to create a setting and a control. Like under here:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('Some_color', array(
    'default' => '#fffff',
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
));
    $wp_customize->add_control(
    new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'Some_color',
        array(
            'label' => __('Some_color', 'DesignitMultistore'),
            'section' => 'Some Section',
            'priority' => 1,
        )
    ));
```

Code from sanitize_hex_color :
[Codelink wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_hex_color/)

So one example from you converted :

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('header_backgroundcolor', array(
'default' => '#f8f8f8',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_hex_color',
));

$wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'header_backgroundcolor', array(
      'label'      => __( 'Header Background Color' ),
      'section'    => 'colors',
      'settings'   => 'header_backgroundcolor',
    ) ) );
```

Also are you working with Less or Sass or are you having a style html?

Comment: thanks again for introducing me to the sanitize functionality (can't believe I missed it). Am currently using style html, but if I could build from Less, SaSS or the Stylus port of Bootstrap dynamically that'd be awesome.